# javascript regex for querysting with anchor

Tags: javascript, regex, testing, anchor, query-string

I am making a web app that has multiple 'pages' but it will all be loaded client side. Seems how it is all technically on the same page, I will be using parameters after # to track the current page state while preventing postbacks. My problem is that I cant seem to select all the parameters with a regex line. The regex for split works when I use a testing tool online but does not work when I use it on my web page.

```
//Test data for url
//https://test.ca?hi&hey=3&test=oh+hi+mark#edit&e=1

var split = /([^&#=]+)=?([^&#]*)/g;
var url = window.location.href;
var match = split.exec(url);

//this outputs match with a length of three 
//[0] = 'https://test.ca?hi'
//[1] = 'https://test.ca?hi'
//[2] = ''
```

I thought this should be a solved problem but I cant seem to find an answer. Which I guess leads to another question. Am I going about this the completely wrong way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the regex wrong. You just print the whole match, while you need to access the captured groups while iterating through all the matches inside 1 string.

Here is an example snippet:

```js
var re = /([^&#=]+)=?([^&#]*)/g; 
var str = 'https://test.ca?hi&hey=3&test=oh+hi+mark#edit&e=1';
var match;
 
while ((match = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    document.write(match[1] + "<br/>" + match[2] + "<br/><br/>");
}
```

Note that the first match is the "main" part of the URL. Subsequent matches are param-value pairs.

Comment: This loop is what I was missing, I now see how it goes through each set of values. Thanks for the prompt response.

Answer (score 0):

Try using window.location.hash instead. It will return the hash value (in your example url it would be #edit&e=1) and you can use string operations to do whatever you need to with that.